# Can the "Change Shape" monster feature be used to impersonate a specific NPC?

Tags: dnd-5e, shapeshifting

Multiple monster have a variant of the "Change Shape" ability.

For example, the Night Hag can transform into a small or medium sized female humanoid:

> **Change Shape**. The hag magically polymorphs into a Small or Medium female humanoid, or back into her true form. Her statistics are the same in each form.

Similarly, the Deva can change into a humanoid or beast:

> **Change Shape**. The deva magically polymorphs into a humanoid or beast that has a challenge rating equal to or less than its own, or back into its true form.

Can Change Shape be used to impersonate a specific NPC?

Comment: The answer for "Shapechanger" applies here, as there are [no meaningful mechanical differences](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/191806/what-are-the-mechanical-differences-between-shapechanger-and-change-shape/191807#191807) between "Shapechanger" and "Change Shape"